# Is hiding an algorithm necessary?

Tags: java, android, security

I just want to clarify in data security, I'm using SecreteKeyFactory object to generate a secrete key. This will be used in encrypting/decrypting a data.

here is my code

```
 private SecretKey getKey(String user_id, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    SecretKey secretKey = null;

    String PBE_SHA256_256BitAES_CBC_BC                  = "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC";
    String AES_ENCRYPTION                               = "AES";

    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBE_SHA256_256BitAES_CBC_BC);
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(user_id.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), Constants.ITERATION_COUNT, Constants.KEY_LENGTH);

    secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), AES_ENCRYPTION );

    return  secretKey;
}
```

My question would be. Is it necessary to hide the algorithm used for obtaining secretkey? If not, where should we store the algorithm so that we can increase the security?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, hiding the algorithm is not necessary. Doing so would be [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and would create only a false sense of security. In any well-designed cryptosystem, the keys are the only thing that ever need to be kept secret.

Comment: @shinta This concept is known as [Kirchoffs' Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle).